# Symfony 4: Fetching user from DB ind custom user provider returns "Bad Credentials"

Tags: api, symfony, jwt, symfony4, lexikjwtauthbundle

I am building an API based on Symfony 4.

In my custom user provider I dump the users email and the user data from database.
The email is shown but the second dump does not appear.
While fetching the user data it returns "Bad Credentials".

Here is my user provider:

```
<?php
// src/Security/User/WebserviceUserProvider.php
namespace App\Security\User;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;

class WebserviceUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    private $doctrine;

    public function __construct (\Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry $doctrine)
    {
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    }

    public function loadUserByUsername($email)
    {
        var_dump($email);
        $userData = $this->doctrine->getManager()
            ->createQueryBuilder('SELECT u FROM users u WHERE u.email = :email')
            ->setParameter('email', $email)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult();
        var_dump($userData);exit;
        // pretend it returns an array on success, false if there is no user

        if ($userData) {
            $username = $userData['email'];
            $password = $userData['password'];
            $salt = $userData['salt'];
            $roles = $userData['roles'];

            // ...

            return new WebserviceUser($username, $password, $salt, $roles);
        }

        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
            sprintf('Username "%s" does not exist.', $username)
        );
    }

    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof WebserviceUser) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(
                sprintf('Instances of "%s" are not supported.', get_class($user))
            );
        }

        return $this->loadUserByUsername($user->getUsername());
    }

    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return WebserviceUser::class === $class;
    }
}
```

If I send my json login data it returns the following:

```
string(13) "test@test.com" {"code":401,"message":"Bad credentials"}
```

Does anyone know this problem?

Comment: Have you created the WebserviceUser class? However, if you are loading users from the database, I'd suggest following this instead: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/entity_provider.html

Comment: the code you gave us is probably not the current one, since your `exit` would end all of it, and only one `var_dump` actually triggers.

Comment: @Gimsly
Yes, I have created the WebserviceUser class. If i load the user by repository the result is the same. I never get the result of the query. It alway throws the 401 json error.

Comment: @Jakumi 
I know. I only want to dump the database object.